# Нет метода Json в JsonResult Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: json, asp.net-core

В ASP.Core 2 работал контроллер

```
    [HttpGet]

    public JsonResult GetGrafic(int ResourceId)
    {
        var sheduling = new List<Sheduling>();
        var events = from e in _context.GraficResource.Where(c => c.ResourceId == ResourceId)
                     select new
                     {
                         id = e.Id,
                         title = e.Personals.Name,
                         start = e.DateStart,
                         end = e.DateStop,
                         color = e.Personals.Color,
                         personalId = e.PersonalId,
                         description = e.ClientName
                     };
        var rows = events.ToList();

        return Json(rows);
    }
```

В Core 2.1

```
return Json(rows);
```

пишет что Json не существует в текущем контексте. Если убираем Json, оставляя просто:

```
return rows;
```

то пишет что не удалось неявно преобразовать тип List() в JsonResult

Как теперь конвертировать в Json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ дали в английской версии [Ответ на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101100/jsonresult-return-json-in-asp-net-core-2-1).
Моя ошибка была в том что я не посмотрел на созданный класс  Controller. А он в CORE 2.1 был сгенерирован как [ControllerBase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-2.1) в котором нет Json(объекта). Соответсвенно было два пути либо заменить ControllerBase на Controller. 
Или заменить:

```
return Json(rows);
```

на

```
return new JsonResult(rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего необходимо подключить зависимую библиотеку Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll через Nuget.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Это пакет входит в пакет Microsoft.AspNetCore.App а он ставится по умолчанию.